# loop through all array items for each item

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, p5.js

I am trying to iterate through the array and assign each item to all the others. Currently on *console.log(i,j)* it does do this indeed but my code does not work otherwise. In the console you will see:

- 1,1
- 1,2
- 1,3
- ...etc...
- 19,18
- 19,19

The problem I believe is that it is creating *anchorConnectors[i * j]* is creating array at indexes that are not consecutive, which I don't think works. Maybe I am missing something else. Thank you to anyone for any help in advance. I sincerely appreciate it.

```
var anchorPoints = [];
var anchorConnectors = [];
var anchorPointAmount = 20;
var xvals = [];
var yvals = [];
const cenX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const cenY = window.innerHeight / 2;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    frameRate(60);
    for (i = 0; i < anchorPointAmount; i++) {
        xvals.push(random(0, window.innerWidth));
        yvals.push(random(0, window.innerHeight));
        anchorPoints[i] = new AnchorPoint(xvals[i], yvals[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < anchorPointAmount; j++) {
             console.log(i, j)
             anchorConnectors[j * i] = new AnchorConnector(xvals[i], yvals[i], xvals[j * 2], yvals[j * 2]);
        }
     }
     console.log(xvals);
     console.log(yvals);
}
```

Comment: u r assigning random indexes in anchorConnectors. So 0*1 (j x i) = 0 and 0*2 = 0. Thus on two iterations 0th index value will be overwritten. I think you probably need a two dimension array - anchorConnectors[i][j] and not anchorConnectors[i*j]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the array values are not consecutive. That doesn't matter at all.

Take a closer look at your logic:

```
for (i = 0; i < anchorPointAmount; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < anchorPointAmount; j++) {
    anchorConnectors[j * i] = // something
  }
}
```

Now, run through this in your head with some example values. Let's say `anchorPointAmount` is `3`. Your loop iterations look like this:

- `i=0`, `j=0`, `j*i=0` (you assign index `0` to something)
- `i=0`, `j=1`, `j*i=0` (you assign index `0` to something)
- `i=0`, `j=2`, `j*i=0` (you assign index `0` to something)
- `i=1`, `j=0`, `j*i=0` (you assign index `0` to something)
- `i=1`, `j=1`, `j*i=1` (you assign index `1` to something)
- `i=1`, `j=2`, `j*i=2` (you assign index `2` to something)
- `i=2`, `j=0`, `j*i=0` (you assign index `0` to something)
- `i=2`, `j=1`, `j*i=2` (you assign index `2` to something)
- `i=2`, `j=2`, `j*i=4` (you assign index `4` to something)

In other words, you're simply overwriting whatever value was at these indexes a bunch of times, which is not what you want to do.

You're probably looking for a **2D array**. Google is your friend, but the basics would look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < anchorPointAmount; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < anchorPointAmount; j++) {
    anchorConnectors[j][i] = // something
  }
}
```